# conjure-up openstack error "error: flag provided but not defined: --upload-tool"

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, lxd, conjure-up

laptop with fresh/clean install of 16.04.2

installed conjure-up, lxc, lxd, etc...

initialized lxd networking

can launch lxd containers and install nginx, apache, etc.

run "conjure-up openstack", select Openstack with Nova LXD, select localhost.

Error is:

"error: flag provided but not defined: --upload-tool"

I'm still trying to sort out all the responsibilities and relationships between lxd, juju, maas, openstack, conjure-up, etc.  so I'm not even really sure where to start looking.

openstack.log:

```
Mar  5 11:04:04 laptop openstack: [WARNING] pollinate binary not found
Mar  5 11:04:08 laptop openstack: message repeated 2 times: [ [WARNING] pollinate binary not found]
Mar  5 11:04:08 laptop openstack: [ERROR] ['error: flag provided but not defined: --upload-tools']
Mar  5 11:04:08 laptop openstack: [WARNING] pollinate binary not found
```

syslog (same as openstack.log):

```
Mar  5 11:04:04 laptop openstack: [WARNING] pollinate binary not found
Mar  5 11:04:08 laptop openstack: message repeated 2 times: [ [WARNING] pollinate binary not found]
Mar  5 11:04:08 laptop openstack: [ERROR] ['error: flag provided but not defined: --upload-tools']
Mar  5 11:04:08 laptop openstack: [WARNING] pollinate binary not found
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but "pollinate binary not found" appears to be related to conjure-up [having issues with instalingl OpenStack with LXD via conjure-up against Maas 2.0](install OpenStack with LXD via conjure-up against Maas 2.0) but it seems that this bug was squashed on Jun 9,2016.  I found mention of your other error [here](https://github.com/conjure-up/conjure-up/issues/8) which indicates a new version of conjure-up may be required. There's also an informative user manual [here](http://conjure-up.io/docs/en/users/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it turns out conjure-up and juju are quite picky about each other's versions.  after lots of attempts, this solved my issue:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge juju*
sudo apt-get remove --purge conjure-up
sudo snap install conjure-up --classic

conjure-up
```

here's the versions I am now running:

```
$ juju --version
  2.1.1-xenial-amd64
$ conjure-up --version
  conjure-up 2.1.1
```

before this, I was running something like juju 2.0, and conjure-up 0.1.2.

Comment: You dont need the ppas any longer, just a `sudo snap install conjure-up --classic` will give you everything you need.

Comment: tested on fresh 16.04 install.  you are correct, thank you.

Comment: After `sudo snap install conjure-up --classic` I do not have the commands `juju` and `conjure-up`. Ubuntu 16.04 tells me to install them via `apt`